# Use enable_if for class member function with sperate definition

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a template binary tree class (for learning).

I have the following definition:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class binary_tree final
{
...
public:
template <typename TParam,
          typename = enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, remove_reference_t<TParam>>::value>>
    void insert(TParam &&data);

};
```

And I'm trying to add the implementation for `insert` at the bottom of the header file:

```cpp
template<typename T>
template <typename TParam,
          typename = enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, remove_reference_t<TParam>>::value>>
void binary_tree<T>::insert(TParam &&data)
{
    binary_tree_ptr &insert_location = data > _data ? _right : _left;
    if (!insert_location)
        insert_location = binary_tree_ptr(new binary_tree(std::forward<TParam>(data)));
    else
        insert_location->insert(std::forward<TParam>(data));
}
```

This won't compile, with the following error, pointing to the implementation:

```
cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template
```

If I remove the `typename = ...` from the implementation, I get the following error:

```
out-of-line definition of 'insert' does not match any declaration in 'binary_tree<T>'
```

Removing the `typename = ...` from the declaration doesn't yield anything better.

What am I missing? Is there A way to do that?

I'm compiling using clang 6.

Comment: Default arguments should go in the declaration, not definition, same as for default arguments in regular functions. Your definition should use `template <typename TParam,
          typename>`

Comment: What if you declare second template parameter as `typename  enable_if...`?

Comment: @super thanks, I guess I didn't think about the second parameter as being nameless... This solved the problem!